# Is it possible to pause an automation that is already running using SSJS in SFMC?

Tags: api, ssjs

I have created an SSJS script which aims to start and stop mass automation. While both functions work normally, I noticed that when an automation is already running and I run the script, it does not stop, but pauses ONLY after it is completed. I'm looking for a way to make it stop while running. Is that possible ?

Kind Regards,
Efthymis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop an automation that is currently running you will need to use the following REST API (This is what is being used in the UI of SFMC as well with the 'stop' button.) It is undocumented, but is fairly safe to use as it is utilized in UI.

```
POST /legacy/v1/beta/bulk/automations/automation/definition/?action=stop
Host: {{tse}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}

{"id":"{{myAutoID}}","scheduleObject":{}}
```

As a note though, you cannot use the GUID version of the AutomationID that you get from SOAP/WSProxy, but instead you will need to use the identifier used internally (Can be found in URL of automation as well as pulled from REST API call)

Finding it in url:

```
https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Automation%20Studio/AutomationStudioFuel3/%23Instance/{{MYAUTOID}}
```

REST API Endpoint to get this:

```
GET /legacy/v1/beta/bulk/automations/automation/definition/
Host: {{tse}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot for your answer.

Can you please elaborate on how to utilize the automation URL in the Rest API call?

I would like to stop them masse and while they are running.

If I understood correctly in the proposed solution, I should put the URL of each automation in the script (API CALL). correct?

Is this the only way to implement it?

My goal is that when I run the script, all the automations which I've added with the AutomationId in this Data Extension stop even if they've started running.

Comment: I have not attempted to do a single call to stop a bulk of automations, but I would say more than likely its a 1:1 call. So you would need to make an individual call for each Automation.

Comment: as you said, it worked grate! there is a corresponding API call for the "run once" case as well ?

Comment: @themistsoupros Run all once (from Auto Studio Dash button): `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{autoid}}/actions/runallonce`  and to mimic the run once in the Auto page itself that allows you to choose which activities is `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{autoid}}/actions/start`. But will need a JSON payload with this. Sample: `{"steps": [{"activities": [{"id": "XXXXXXXX","IsIncludedInRun": true}]}]}`